# I am facing an error net::ERR_ABORTED 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my `componentDidMount` function I have a problem.

I'm facing `error 401` in my Reactjs site, my username and password are correct.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Json Datalog") fetch('185.213.180.129:9900/cgi-bin/datalog.json', {
        'mode': 'no-cors'
      }, {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: 'include',
        headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.state.deviceSettings.userName + ":" + this.state.deviceSettings.password),
        }
      }).then((response) => {
          console.log("Btoa Encryption::::: ", btoa(this.state.deviceSettings.userName + ":" + this.state.deviceSettings.password))
```

Comment: some headers might be missing? can you post the respective code?

Comment: yes maybe something is missed

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Json Datalog")
     fetch('http://185.213.180.129:9900/cgi-bin/datalog.json', { 'mode': 'no-cors' },
      {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: 'include',
          headers: {
            
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.state.deviceSettings.userName + ":" + this.state.deviceSettings.password),
          }
          
        }).then((response) => {
          console.log("Btoa Encryption::::: ", btoa(this.state.deviceSettings.userName + ":" + this.state.deviceSettings.password))

Comment: if (response.ok) {
            return response.json()
          }
          return {}
        }).then((json) => {
          console.log(json, 'apex')
          this.extractApexParameters(json)
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err)
          this.setState({ isFetchingProps: false }, () => {
            if (this.notification) {
              this.notification.showNotification(`Unfortunately, we were unable to connect to device`, true)
            }
          })
        })
    }

Comment: you should add the codes in your post instead of comment area.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean

Comment: See the updates one of it I have done please add the respective codes to the post.

Comment: yes if you can send me ur email to tell you what is my problem exactly

Comment: that's not how SO works ... update the **question** with the relevant code - dont' post code in a comment

Comment: is `185.213.180.129:9900` same origin or cross origin? because if it's cross origin, and you've set mode `no-cors`, then you WONT be able to read the response - that's what no-cors does ... allows you to make a cross origin request with no access to the response

Comment: I see the issue ... you are calling fetch like `fetch(url, object, object)` ... but `fetch` only takes at most two arguments, `resource (url)` and `init` .. try combining the 2nd and 3rd arguments into a single (second) argument

Comment: yes true but when i remove no-cors another error will appear which is (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.)

Comment: yes, I see what you've done wrong, see answer

Comment: yes its a good try but another error appear that ( Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Failed to parse URL from 185.213.180.129:9900/cgi-bin/datalog.json)

Comment: "it's a good try" ... lol ... your code doesn't send authentication header for the reasons given ... so, it's not "a good try", it's what you've done WRONG in your attempt to bypass CORS - you can't bypass CORS, because CORS is how servers prevent resource "borrowing"

Comment: no i removed CORS but there is another error that it is failed to execute 'fetch'

Answer (score 2):

You're passing three arguments to fetch

effectively you are using fetch like

```
fetch('185.213.180.129:9900/cgi-bin/datalog.json', {
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
```

So your authentication header is not set at all

try this instead

```
fetch('185.213.180.129:9900/cgi-bin/datalog.json', {
    mode: 'no-cors',
    method: "GET",
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.state.deviceSettings.userName + ":" + this.state.deviceSettings.password),
    }
  })
```

also, you need to understand what `mode: 'no-cors'` means - you will not have access to the response body if the request is not same origin - so forget reading the response as per the code in your comments (i.e. `return response.json()` ) - you will not get any access to the response using `mode: 'no-cors'`

Comment: You have no idea how hepful this answer is to me... I was struggling to debug this from last 3-4 days. Also can you tell me one more thing? If I remove `mode: 'no-cors'` I get cors error, how can I avoid that ? I am requesting to a backend whose access I don't have I can only modify my frontend code